# What "other features" could be incorporated into a train database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, database-design

This is a mini project for DBMS course. My task is to develop a Database for management of passenger trains.

I'm designing tables for Customers, Trains, Ticket Booking (via Telephone & Internet), Origins and Destinations.

He said, we are free to incorporate other features in our Database Model. Some of the features that we can include are as listed:

1. Ad-hoc Querying
2. Data Mining
3. Demographic Passenger Mapping
4. Origin and Destination Mapping

I've no clue about what these features mean. I know about datamining but unable to apply it in this context. Can any one kindly expand these features or suggest new ideas?

**EDIT:** What is Ad-hoc Querying? Give an example in this context.

Comment: Why? the tag adds nothing and he described in the post that it's assignment.

Comment: A good feature would be ServerFault.

Comment: @Oded ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812)

Answer (score 2):

Data mining would incorporate extracting useful facts/figures out of the data obtained by your system & stored in the database.  For example, data mining might discover that trains between city x and y are always 5 minutes late, or is never at more than 50% capacity, etc.  So you may wish to develop some tools or scripts that automatically run and generate statistics (graphs are best) which display this information and highlight unusual trends.  In the given example, the schedulers could then analyse why the trains are always late (e.g., maybe the train speedos are wrong?).

Both points 3. and 4. are a subset of data mining imo.  There is a huge amount of metrics you could try to measure, it is just really whatever you can think of.  If you specify what type of data you are going to collect, that will make making suggestions easier.

Basically, data mining just means "sort the data to find interesting facts".

Based on comment below you could look for,

- % of internet vs. phone sales
- popular destinations & origins
- customers age/sex/location
- usage vs. time of day
- ...

Comment: I'm designing tables for Customers, Trains, Ticket Booking (via Telephone & Internet), Origins and Destinations.

Comment: So, these are external scripts/programs(That fetch data from Database (using SQL) and print some facts after analysis.)? What I mean is, this has nothing to do with either database or its design right?

Comment: They could be anything - SQL scripts, <insert language here> programs, excel spreadsheets.  "data mining" is a topic, it's no magic thing.  It just means "to mine data".  Whatever tools you use to do that, is up to you.  The database design may  be influenced by your queries, depending on their complexity.  e.g., if it's complex to work out how much a ticket cost, but it's used in a lot of queries, you may add a column to store this data to reduce the time the queries take.

Comment: can you kindly throw some light on "1. Ad-hoc Querying". I didn't get what it even means?

Comment: ad-hoc kinda means random, un-organised.  So I'm guessing they mean something like "random, unknown querying".  So pretty much they want the ability to throw together random queries in the future as they desire.  So maybe you'd have a form on your program where the user can select a field (e.g., cost of ticket) then set some other parameter (e.g., less than $1, more than 20c) and then hit "run".  The results would be displayed.  They could then change the parameters, and run again for different results.  I believe this would be ad-hoc querying.  hope that helped.

Comment: I see. But I don't get how a query like this is ad-hoc or random? How is it not an organized query? He is asking for `SELECT *
FROM Tickets WHERE price >= 0.2 AND price <= 1`

Comment: well, if you make the `0.2` and `1` variable, it is ad hoc!  The user can change and play with those settings to run different queries.  If it was fixed to 0.2 and 1, then it would be statix/fixed and not ad-hoc.  That would be about the most basic form of ad-hoc query you could get.  Obviously more fields = more variables = more complex.  The fact that when you right the query you don't know what the result will be (because part of the query is variable) makes it adhoc IMO.